# What is the safe and idiomatic way to check if two records (and two types in general) are equal in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

It seems like the codebase I'm working on complains if I'm using `=` or `<>` to check equality or inequality of two types that are not `int` types.

I assume this was disabled so that I can't do the wrong thing. If this is true, what is the right way to check (deep) equality between two records?

Answer (score 2):

`=` and `<>` seem to work pretty well for records.

```
# type a = {b: int; c: string};;
type a = { b : int; c : string; }
# {b=42; c="hello"} = {b=42; c="hello"};;
- : bool = true
# {b=42; c="hello"} <> {b=42; c="hello"};;
- : bool = false
```

Also seems to work pretty well for recursive variant types.

```
# type d = E | F of int * d;;
type d = E | F of int * d
# F (3, E) = F (3, E);;
- : bool = true
# F (3, E) = F (3, (F (8, E)));;
- : bool = false
```

Now, if this isn't working for you with anything other than `int` it's almost certainly because you're using the Base library which does not support polymorphic comparison operators.

If you must use Base, the [`Poly`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/v0.12/doc/base/Base/Poly/index.html) module contains polymorphic comparison operators.

Comment: yeah I use Core, it seems like the rest of the codebase tends to implement `equal / compare` via ppx derive. Is there a downside to using `Poly.compare` instead?

Comment: @David天宇Wong `Poly.compare` does the wrong thing for certain complex types.  For example, a set or map is typically implemented as a balanced binary tree, and there are multiple trees that have different shapes (and thus are not equal according to `Poly.compare`) but are semantically equivalent. This issue is why Base discourages use of the polymorphic operators.

Comment: that makes sense! I think this would be true for records that have pointers to C structs in them as well no?